# Assigning value to Java variable after querying from Mongo DB with Mongo Java driver(3.x)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

How to assign the values queried from MongoDB to a variable in Java using Mongo Java Driver?

```
int usr1count;
      MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
            MongoDatabase mongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("testdb3");
            MongoCollection mongoCollection = mongoDatabase.getCollection("sample");
            mongoCollection.drop();
            mongoCollection.insertOne(new Document("_id","usr1").append("count", 1));
            mongoCollection.insertOne(new Document("_id","usr2").append("count", 1));
            mongoCollection.insertOne(new Document("_id","usr3").append("count", 1));
            BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("_id", "usr1");
            FindIterable<Document> fi=mongoCollection.find();
            fi.forEach(new Block<Document>() {
                @Override
                public void apply(final Document document) {
                    Integer.parseInt(document.getString("count").toString());
                }
            });
```

I have to assign usr1count(variable) a value after querying from the Database.
How to assign value present in Integer.parseInt(document.getString("count").toString());

Comment: Did you even try using `interator()` from the `FindIterable`? Or more importantly just `.findOne()` when you "expect" only a single document in reponse?

Comment: Thank you..Mongo cursor is a good option.mongoCollection doesnt have findone option..It has options of findoneanddelete,findoneandupdate or findoneandreplace

Comment: Wow. Between this and the general "balls up" that the C# driver documentation state is in currently, then I'd be lining up the firing squad. How such a basic omission is made from a driver is astonishing.

Comment: Your question **really should be** *"Why cannnot I just retrieve a single matched document with the MongoDB Java driver 3.0"* Or better yet *"Where did .findOne() go in the MongoDB Java Driver 3.0?"*. Upvotes from me and everyone on that title and content.

Comment: Yeah will edit as suggested..

Comment: Still a bit concerned about your question in general though. Did you really "just want" to get a single document and retrieve a property? If so then go ahead and edit. If you wanted to *"Sum all the values for a property over the collection"* then that is another question entirely, for which there is a completely different answer.

Comment: yeah..from a document wanted to get a property in this case, for a user i wanted to retrieve the count property